# Git on Mac: toggle files in working directory (equivalent to -- in Windows)

Tags: git, macos, git-bash

There's a really convenient feature when using the standard Git Shell in Windows that comes with GitHub's official Desktop client.  If you have files in the working directory, you can type `--` and then <kbd>tab</kbd> to toggle through all the files in the working directory.  Example:

`git add -- <tab><tab><tab>`

Is there an equivalent way to toggle through files in the working directory using Terminal on Mac OSX?  This feature is particularly useful if I only want to stage a few files and there are many files in the working directory that are deeply nested in the file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to [install the Git Bash Completions](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion).

Comment: I don't know if this does the same thing, but I ended up installing [git-completion](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash). Instructions are [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Basics-Tips-and-Tricks) although I had to add the `source ~/git-completion.bash` code into `.bash_profile` and not `.bashrc`.  This seems to have also done the trick.

Comment: I believe they're equivalent, yes.